# Phalcon\Mvc\Model::find() together with Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Query\Builder

Tags: php, phalcon

I am trying to use Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Query\Builder object together with Phalcon\Mvc\Model::find() method to customize data load behaviour.

All model rows in the table have "record_status" field which is used to mark records active/inactive.

I intend to extend Model::find() and Model::findFirst() methods to always add "record_status=1" constraint to all my Model queries. But for now, I'm just trying to pass Query\Builder object on to ::find() method externally:

```
class User extends Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{
}

$user = new User();

/**
 * @var Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Query\Builder
 */
$query = $user->getModelsManager()->createBuilder();

$query->where('email = :email:', [
    'email' => 'root@yahoo.com'
])->andWhere('record_status = :status:', [
    'status' => 1
])->from('users');

$found = $user->find($query);

foreach ($found as $foundUser) {
    ...
}
```

The problem is that **->find($query)** returns ALL rows from the database, ignoring WHERE clauses set to $query.

When inspecting properties of $query & $user I see the following relevant protected properties:

```
$query::_conditions = '(email = :email:) AND (record_status = :status:)';
$query::_bindParams = array(
    'email' => 'root@yahoo.com',
    'status' => 1
);

$user::_count = 4; // This is wrong, this corresponds to TOTAL number of rows
$user::_result->_bindParams = NULL; // Bound parameters have disappeared
$user::_result->_sqlStatement = 'SELECT `users`.`id`,  `users`.`email`, `users`.`record_status` FROM `users`'; // As you can see, there is no WHERE clause
```

I'm on Phalcon 1.3.0, PHP 5.5.1.

I expect find() and findFirst() methods to accept Query\Builder() object and fetch the correct records. Is this a bug or am I approaching it incorrectly?

Thanks,
Temuri

Answer (score 3):

Yep you have things wrong.

The `Model::find()` and `Model::findFirst()` functions accept arrays, int or string and are wrappers for query builder.

You have at least two options:

a) use query builder directly:

```
// ... here is your query builder script as in question
$results = $query->getQuery()->execute();
$firstFound = $results->getFirst();
```

b) pass array to `Model::findFirst()`:

```
$firstFound = User::findFirst(
    array(
        '(email = :email:) AND (record_status = :status:)',
        'bind' => array('email' => 'root@yahoo.com', 'status' => 1)
   )
);
```

Comment: Wish it was that simple.. Please look at this thread:

http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/936/phalcon-mvc-model-find-together-with-phalcon-mvc-model-query-bui#C3576